# InDesign CC: Placed Illustrator file does not fit on page

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have created an artboard in Illustrator with the same dimensions af an InDesign document. But when I place my Illustrator file in my InDesign document, the length is off (not the height though!)

Illustrator file:
[image]

InDesign document:
[image]

What am I missing? It's driving me isane.

**UPDATE:** It seems InDesign is cutting off the right side of the graphic, even though the frame is the same size as the artboard:

InDesign:
[image]
[image]

Illustrator:
[image]

Comment: Check the size of that `graphic frame` **and** the `graphic` inside it. Maybe one of them has been resized **or** maybe the `graphic` inside the frame has shifted. In the more recent versions of Indesign, it's super easy to make that mistake where you try to move an image, accidentally drag it from the center and end up moving the `graphic` instead of the `graphic frame`. Having `Auto-fit` checked could cause it too.  I'd find it much more helpful to debug the issue if the placed image was like a photo, so I could easily see if anything is off. Like if it's been stretched or copped.

Comment: Frame and graphic are the same size and are placed correctly. There is nothing outside the frame or the artboard. However, I found out that InDesign seems to cut of the graphic in that end, even though the frame as big as the artboard.

Comment: Is it possible it's a white object on top? I didn't mention it before, but the Indesign image before the update seems to show a light blue border between the orange and the white, which would indicate some sort of frame edge...  Locks could make such object untouchable. It's not visible in the updated Indesign image though.. — What if you try to make a completely new document and place the graphic there? Also is it possible for you to package the document and like Dropbox link to the file so we can take a look. You can strip it down to this orange graphic and one page if necessary.

Comment: I literally just created a blank InDesign document and placed my Illustrator file in it. So there shouldn't be any objects in it. Also if I move the placed object the what border follows with it. If I select the object inside the frame, the selection shows that the object isn't bigger than what is insert (see the new image the original post). Thanks for trying though.

Comment: I'm completely baffled. The `graphic frame` clearly extends to the full width of what the `graphic` is supposed to be. In this new screenshot we can see the `graphic` is cut off as if it was never that wide. This should not happen, because you can't crop the `graphic` without the `graphic frame`, you can only stretch it. Without fiddling with either of the files, I can't really say much more. This should absolutely not happen. I'm pretty convinced this is a bug. Perhaps doing a preferences reset could help.

Comment: I'd be curious to see what would happen if you embedded the link and unembedded it to a new file. Would it be cut off if you open the new file in AI. —You should perhaps post this in the Adobe forums too.

Answer (score 1):

Is there *live text*, clipping masks, etc, in Illustrator or is it *really* only a color-filled box?

I suspect there's text..

Live text tends to add to the left side of the "art". So when placing into InDesign, one needs to import the AI file using the "Trim" or "Bleed" options for the import. `File > Place` and tick the `Show Import Options` tick box. Or hold the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> keydown when choosing `File > Place`.

[image]

Then in the second dialog window, choose Trim or Bleed under the `Options/Crop to`

[image]

Comment: I have tried all of this. Unfortunately it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the element have been placed outside the artboard, just try to drag it to the right.

Also, check if it have been placed inside a placeholder frame, then you could just make that frame bigger.

And you could also try to just copy/paste from Illustrator to inDesign.

Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: As you can see in the updated post, this is not the problem. However, InDesign seem to cut off the graphic for no reason...